net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error when connecting to vscode marketplace
I cant fetch extensions due to this error in the developer tools console
POST https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

My vscode version
Version: 1.93.1 (user setup)
Commit: 38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40
Date: 2024-09-11T17:20:05.685Z
Electron: 30.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 10073054
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.15.1
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

And yes i have uninstalled vscode and removed all user data and extensions. but the issue still persists
I even cleared SSL state and reset all networks
I tried connecting to marketplace.visualstudio.com on my chromium browsers Arc and Chrome and I got the same
err.
It seems like the error is system wide.
Please is there any way to fix this
I tried reloading extensions side bar and it returned an error. I opened the developer console to seek out what the error was

Is your computer's clock at the correct time?

Yes it is at the correct time.

The NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error usually occurs when a website's SSL server certificate isn't trusted by your system.
The server certificate used by https://marketplace.visualstudio.com (serial number: 3300ca1eee2ffedf9a44df6c36000000ca1ee) seems to be quite new:
Valid from: Tue, 24 Sep 2024 17:56:19 UTC
Valid until: Sun, 23 Mar 2025 17:56:19 UTC
So probably the Issuing certificate or the Root certificate is not in your local systems certificate store - especially if you can reproduce the issue in the browser!
You can check this in Chrome by clicking on the icon directly left from the URL in the browser address line and follow the steps in the screenshots:



